# soa-infra is not starting

Tags: oracle11g, soa, weblogic-10.x, jdeveloper

I installed SOA Suite 11g, Weblogic and Jdeveloper and I try to follow some training.

I user Win Server 2008.

When it comes time to deploy I am not able to connect to the soa_server.

That's when I notice from the em that the soa-infra is down.

I started managedweblogic and I see that soa_server1 is up.

What am I missing and how can I get the soa-infra started?

I would appreciate any help.

What should the classpath point to?

Steve

I found an entry in the log. Maybe that will help to bebug.

(WebAppServletContext.java:449)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.(WebAppServletContext.java:493)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.HttpServer.loadWebApp(HttpServer.java:418)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.registerWebApp(WebAppModule.java:972)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:382)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.prepare(ScopedModuleDriver.java:176)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:199)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$1.next(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:517)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:159)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:45)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:613)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:184)
at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.prepare(EarDeployment.java:58)
at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:154)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:60)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppDeployment.prepare(AppDeployment.java:141)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doPrepare(DeploymentAdapter.java:39)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.prepare(DeploymentAdapter.java:191)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$1.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:21)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:240)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.prepare(ConfiguredDeployments.java:165)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:122)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:180)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:96)
at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.wsdl.WSDLException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:305)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:246)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1791)
at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.getMethods(BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.java:1055)
at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.getMethods(BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.java:1074)
at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.getMethods(BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.java:1043)
at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.processJ2eeAnnotations(BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.java:99)
at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.J2eeAnnotationProcessor.processJ2eeAnnotations(J2eeAnnotationProcessor.java:37)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAnnotationProcessorImpl.processServlets(WebAnnotationProcessorImpl.java:226)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAnnotationProcessorImpl.processJ2eeAnnotations(WebAnnotationProcessorImpl.java:209)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAnnotationProcessorImpl.processAnnotations(WebAnnotationProcessorImpl.java:105)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.processAnnotations(WebAppServletContext.java:1368)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.(WebAppServletContext.java:449)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.(WebAppServletContext.java:493)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.HttpServer.loadWebApp(HttpServer.java:418)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.registerWebApp(WebAppModule.java:972)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:382)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.prepare(ScopedModuleDriver.java:176)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:199)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$1.next(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:517)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:159)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:45)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:613)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:184)
at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.prepare(EarDeployment.java:58)
at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:154)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:60)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppDeployment.prepare(AppDeployment.java:141)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doPrepare(DeploymentAdapter.java:39)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.prepare(DeploymentAdapter.java:191)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$1.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:21)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:240)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.prepare(ConfiguredDeployments.java:165)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:122)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:180)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:96)
at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In normal circumstances soa-infra should start.  Given that it hasn't and policy manager also hasn't started then there is a problem in the configuration or database connectivity.

Search in %MW_HOME%\user_projects\domains\servers\soa_server1\logs\soa_server1-diagnostic.log for any exceptions.  Also have a look at the soa_server1.out file in the same directory.  Clues will be more apparent there.

Most likely it is a datasource issue and checking the data sources - right click on WebLogic/domains/your_domain and select Data Sources option.  Select monitor and it will show you the current state of all data sources.